# Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I get error ' Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified'
when i run
roc_auc_score(y1_test,predictions)
Value of  predictions is
['0' '0' '0' ..., '0' '0' '0']
The decision tree classifier gets predictions as quoted string numpy array.
I converted this to
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
using
predictionsb= predictions.astype(int)
However trying 
roc_auc_score(y1_test,predictionsb)
i get the same error. Numpy doesnt have any binary data type . Any suggestions ?
Went through existing posts but no luck

Comment: try `print(set(y1_test))` and `print(set(predictions))`. If you don't see `[0, 1]` for both of them they are wrong. Scikit-learn is expecting an array with only `[0, 1]` values.

Comment: You can use something like this `y = np.where(y > 0, True, False)` to force a numpy array into binary values. Also you should understand why you are `y1_test` or `predictions` are not binary, and also why they are `str`, that is really weird for my limited experience on `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help the y1_test too was in string  form..Guess had been too sleepy :)